# regex to match string and the repeated pattern up to n times

Tags: regex

I have a string that has 4 parts:

string-number up to 99-number up to 99-number up to 99

the part (-number up to 99) appears 1 to 3 times only

the string can still have -other stuff after the last repeat of the -number up to 99 or it can be just that part

now the input can be

1. wan-1051-1-3
2. ss-99-98-97-some other stuff i don't need
3. shelf-11
4. ut-2-1
5. ajshkh-sjahkdjh-sjhka
6. x-10-1

now 1 is wrong because one of the numbers is over 99 and 5 is wrong because it doesn't match at all

input 2 should return the 3 numbers(99,98,97)

i tried that regex \w+(-\d{1,2})*, but it gets wan-10 as a match who shouldn't be the case, any help with that?

Comment: You probably just want `^\w+(?:-\d{1,2})*\b` or - limiting the hyphen with number pattern to one to three - `^\w+(?:-\d{1,2}){1,3}\b`

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you are repeating the capture group which will capture the value of the last iteration.

If you want the 3 numbers (possibly without a leading `-`) you can use a repeating non capture group within that capture group.

```
^\w+-(\d{1,2}(?:-\d{1,2}){0,2})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+-` Match 1+ word chars followed by `-`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
  - `(?:-\d{1,2}){0,2}` Repeat 0-2 times matching `-` and 1-2 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q6go2w/1).

If you want to capture -99-89-97 then then pattern can be shortened to:

```
^\w+((?:-\d{1,2}){1,3})\b
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s3Z9Dg/1).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:-

`^\w+(?:-\d{1,2}){1,3}\b`